# Display data that already loaded Angular JS

Tags: html, angularjs

I have an chtml page using Angular Js that contains list with objects from database
but it takes a long time to load the data.
how can I load just 10 objects and display them, and than continue to load the data 
and show the rest of data in Angular Js????

Comment: are you asking about pagination or breakup while loading ??

Comment: if you want pagination you can refer this link :-

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581209/angularjs-pagination-on-a-list-using-ng-repeater][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581209/angularjs-pagination-on-a-list-using-ng-repeater

Comment: I dont want pagination.I want to see the data display slowly,now it loads some seconnds and than display all the data.I want to see part of data immediatly

Comment: You would have to separate the call to multiple synchronous calls, like call to fetch the first 20, then next 20 and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a lot of data that you want to slowly load to the front end so you don't have to wait. The only method I can think of for adding data periodically would be a setInterval.

the key would be to create a new variable

```
$scope.displayObjects = []
```

That you could contiously append to like so

```
for(var x = currentIndex; x < currentIndex + step && x < $scope.objects.length; x++){
    $scope.displayObjects.push($scope.objects[x]);                        
}
```

Then just set up an interval to continuously call that. You will also need to make use of

```
$scope.$apply()
```

to tell angular to re-apply itself (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$apply).

http://jsfiddle.net/A9uND/20/ You can adjust how much it loads with each step via the step variable.

Next time include a jsfiddle (or something similar) so it's easier to assist you.

While the method outlined above will work, I would suggest tracking how much you can see and then only loading the relevant ones. As you scroll add more along the way.

Comment: Thank you!!I think it will work for me.But i get the data from json file.I use : "$http.get('List.json').success(function (data) )".How can i get just 10 objects from file???

Comment: You wouldn't just get 10 objects, you could get everything. Then iterate over it using a setInterval. So in your case i would store data in $scope.objects then fire a function to set up the interval and continue onwards.