# Pagination with AngularJS or JS on object string or array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, pagination

I'm struggling to implement pagination on another developer's existing code. I've tried implementing some of the solutions explained in a previous SO Post: [Pagination on a list using ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581209/angularjs-pagination-on-a-list-using-ng-repeater)

The code takes a two-dimensional array, parses through it converting to an object of strings, and then displays that on the page. Each object key is used as a column.

Not sure how to utilize [Angular's builtin Limit filter](http://docs-angularjs-org-dev.appspot.com/api/ng.filter:limitTo) with this setup. **I think that would be the ideal solution.** But I'm open to just a JS solution as well. (I've started it out as a JS solution below towards bottom of post.)

```
var data = [["c1","blah","yup","halted","bacon", "blue"],
            ["c2","blank","everything","nothing test"],
            ["c3","test","vista","xp, 7 "],
            ["c4","true"],
            ["c5","do","something else really long text", "and more"]
        ]

$rootScope.resultsObject = parseResults(data);

var columnSize = ["twelve", "six", "four", "three", "two", "two"]

$rootScope.columnCountShow = columnSize[columnCounter($rootScope.resultsObject)-1]

factory('parseResults', function(){
        return function(resultsData){
            var resultsObject = {};
            var column;
            for(var i = 0; resultsData.length > i; i++){
                column = "column" +i;
                resultsObject[column] = resultsData[i].toString().replace(/[\,]/g, "<br>")
            }
            return resultsObject;
        }
    })
```

HTML:

```
<div class="{{columnCountShow}} columns results-column" ng-repeat="resultsObject in resultsObject">
        <div ng-bind-html-unsafe="resultsObject">
</div>
```

How would I go about doing a `show more` style of pagination? It'll go through and display the first 2 results from each array, they click show more, and it loads the next 2, etc.

The current method that I'm using to try and do this: Take the data (before parsed) and slice off a section, and parse only that bit. Then when they select *show more*, it'll take the next few lines, etc.

```
    var limit = 3;
    var start = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var ndata = [[]];
        ndata = data[i].slice(start,limit);
        console.log(ndata);
    }
```

Issue with this, it seems that`data` remains intact. **`slice` doesn't seem to actually remove that portion from the array?**

**Update**

`slice` was definitely not working out for me. Realized JS has a `splice` method. (for some reason I didn't think it existed. My current way of splicing up the data is:

```
$scope.submitWords = function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        var columnCount = columnCounter($scope.keywords);
        var sendObject = keyWordSplit($scope.keywords, columnCount)

        var limit = 2;
        var start = 0;
        var ndata = [[]];
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.testData.length; i++) {
            ndata[i] = $scope.testData[i].splice(start,limit);
            console.log(ndata);
            console.log("original data <br>" + $scope.testData);
        $rootScope.resultsObject = parseResults(ndata);
        }
        var columnSize = ["twelve", "six", "four", "three", "two", "two"];
        $rootScope.columnCountShow = columnSize[columnCounter($rootScope.resultsObject)-1];
    }
```

This correctly splits up the data. Now I just need to have it updating my model. When selecting `show_more()` it replaces the existing data rather than appending to it.

Comment: slice won't remove if you assign it to another variable. Do you have a jsfiddle/plunker?

Comment: No. I began setting one up, but every time I tried running it, I got an error message about using POST instead. I didn't want to take the time to troubleshoot that as well.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/L7CSD/6/ Here is the fiddle. Although I get an error message about needing to use POST. Nothing should be trying to submit. Not sure what to do with that. But now you have a larger source code. Can you help me out?