# Wrapping ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to write a `paginated` directive which works just like `ng-repeat` but preprocessing the iterated collection first (for paging). I thought I could do something like:

```
<tr paginated="item for item in list" page="3" per-page="10">
     <td>[[item.foo]]</td>
     <td>[[item.bar]]</td>
</tr>
```

I want to implement this by reusing `ng-repeat` somehow, but the few vague tries I gave to it didn't work. How could I do that?

This is the best I came up with (note it's not even exactly the same):

```
app.directive('paginated', function() {
    return {
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            data: '=',
            perPage: '@',

        },
        template:
            '<div ng-repeat="item for item in l"><div ng-transclude></div>',

        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngRepeat) {
            scope.l = data;
            // do stuff with scope.l
        },
    }
});
```

Comment: Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tchatel/8LwGE/ It's from Thierry Chatel's Blog entry http://www.frangular.com/2012/12/pagination-cote-client-directive-angularjs.html (french blog about Angular)

Comment: @pdegand59 I'd say that approach is too messy. It monkey-patches data in the parent's scope, and doesn't provide a clean interface. I just want my directive to be a thin layer between ng-repeat and the data in which I alter the data somehow.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a filter to do pagination, here's another stackoverflow question where you can see how it's implemented: [Pagination on a list using ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581209/angularjs-pagination-on-a-list-using-ng-repeater)

Comment: Right, I could do that in the ng-repeat which should be wrapped into my directive. But it's the wrapping I don't know how to do.

Comment: I'm suggesting not doing a directive at all, what you want to accomplish can be done with filters.