# Using Filters to Search in Angular

Tags: angularjs

Folks,

I have a large table (approx 100 columns x 100 rows). Above the table we have a text box to help user search within the table.

What we want is that when the user enters text to search, we display only those rows that match the user's text. The search should be responsive i.e it should narrow down the rows as and when the user enters text.

The code in the template looks something like:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="SearchText" placeholder="Search within table" />
    <table>
    <tr ng-repeat ="row in hugeTableData | customSearchFilter: SearchText">
      <td>row.column1</td>
      <td>row.column2 ..</td>
      <td>row.column100</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

The code in the controller looks like:

```
mpapp. filter('customSearchFilter', function() {
  return function(rows, text) {
    var result = [];
    if (text) {
      var upperCaseText = text.toUpperCase();
      angular.forEach(rows, function(row, i) {
        if (row.alwaysIncludeFlag) {
          result.push(row);
        }
        else {
          var matched = false;
          for each(col in row) {
            var v = row[col];
            if (!angular.isUndefined(v) && v.toUpperCase().indexOf(upperCaseText) >= 0) {
              matched = true;
            }
          }
          if (matched) {
            result.push(row);
          }
        }
      });
    }
    else {
      angular.forEach(rows, function(row) {
        result.push(row);
      });
    }
    return result;
  };
});
```

The problem is that the search is painfully slow. So if I am searching for a word, then  the search text box wouldn't even register the whole word at a time since after each character of the word that the user is entering it goes through this loop.. spends a few seconds .. returns results.. then it registers next character in the textbox .. and so on..

Point is .. this method of search is resulting in absolutely worst user experience.

If anyone has any clued on how to address this better, kindly advice.

Comment: Use `$timeout` service to throttle the filtering.

Comment: could also cache rows as string length increases. Say first letter narrows 100 down to 20, next letter added the search is only 20 elements not 100

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS 'ng-filter' is very slow on array of ~1000 elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17969207/angularjs-ng-filter-is-very-slow-on-array-of-1000-elements)

Comment: Stewie - Coul you please elaborate how the $timeout is to be used to resolve this ?

Comment: Charlieftfl.. how would caching be implemented ?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few speed optimizations you might be able to do.

```
mpapp.filter('customSearchFilter', function() {
    return function(rows, text) {
        if (text) {
            var result = [];        
            var upperCaseText = text.toUpperCase();
            angular.forEach(rows, function(row, i) {
                if (row.alwaysIncludeFlag) {
                    result.push(row);
                }
                else {
                    for(var col in row){
                        var v = row[col];
                        if (!angular.isUndefined(v) && v.toUpperCase().indexOf(upperCaseText) >= 0) {
                            result.push(row);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            return result;
        }
        else {
            return rows;
        }
    };
});
```