# Angular ng-change delay

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an input which filters a ng-repeat list on change. The repeat contains a lot of data and takes a few seconds to filter through everything. I would like their to be 0.5 second delay before I start the filtering process. **What is the correct way in angular to create this delay?**

**Input**

```
 <input ng-model="xyz" ng-change="FilterByName()" />
```

**Repeat**

```
 <div ng-repeat"foo in bar">
      <p>{{foo.bar}}</p>
 </div>
```

**Filter Function**

```
 $scope.FilterByName = function () {
      //Filtering Stuff Here
 });
```

Thanks

Comment: Just use a `$timeout` for 500ms. `$scope.FilterByName = function () { $timeout(_filterByName , 500)`

Comment: @PSL where in the function? I only want the search to execute once. If I just offset it, it will just create a bigger delay and do multiple searches.

Comment: Yeah, in your function. prev comment has a snippet. You can use `$timeout.cancel(timeoutpromise)` if one timeout is in progress and another change gets triggered.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/CSsr3r?p=preview

Comment: `ng-model-options='{ debounce: 1000 }'`

Answer (score 291, accepted):

**AngularJS 1.3+**

Since AngularJS 1.3 you can utilize the `debounce` property [`ngModelOptions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) provides to achieve that very easy without using `$timeout` at all. Here's an example:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='Ctrl'>
    <input type='text' placeholder='Type a name..'
        ng-model='vm.name'
        ng-model-options='{ debounce: 1000 }'
        ng-change='vm.greet()'
    />

    <p ng-bind='vm.greeting'></p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('Ctrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$log',
    function($scope, $log){
        var vm = $scope.vm = {};

        vm.name = '';
        vm.greeting = '';
        vm.greet = function greet(){
            vm.greeting = vm.name ? 'Hey, ' + vm.name + '!' : '';
            $log.info(vm.greeting);
        };
    }
]);
```

-- OR --

**[Check the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j45f147e/)**

**Before AngularJS 1.3**

You'll have to use $timeout to add a delay and probably with the use of $timeout.cancel(previoustimeout) you can cancel any previous timeout and run the new one(helps to prevent the filtering to be executed multiple times consecutovely within a time interval)

Here is an example:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
    var _timeout;

    //...
    //...

    $scope.FilterByName = function() {
        if(_timeout) { // if there is already a timeout in process cancel it
            $timeout.cancel(_timeout);
        }
        _timeout = $timeout(function() {
            console.log('filtering');
            _timeout = null;
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

Comment: Note that `ng-model-options` was only added in [Angular v1.3](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v130-beta6-expedient-caffeination-2014-04-21) (and the debounce property in [beta.8](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#130-beta8-accidental-haiku-2014-05-09)). Those who still need to use an older version of Angular will have to resort to other solutions, like the one from PSL, or by using an external module like [ng-debounce](https://github.com/shahata/angular-debounce).

Comment: A downside could be that this seems to delay validations like ng-pattern as well.

Answer (score 22):

You could use [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) to add a delay and probably with the use of `$timeout.cancel(previoustimeout)` you can cancel any previous timeout and run the new one(helps to prevent the filtering to be executed multiple times consecutovely within a time interval)

Example:-

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  var _timeout;

 //...
 //...

  $scope.FilterByName = function () {
    if(_timeout){ //if there is already a timeout in process cancel it
      $timeout.cancel(_timeout);
    }
    _timeout = $timeout(function(){
      console.log('filtering');
      _timeout = null;
    },500);
  }
 });
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/CSsr3r?p=preview)**

Comment: To the downvoter and future visitors: This answer was added for **Angular 1.2.x**, and added probably before 1.3.x was released which has the the debounce option with ng-model-options and never got a chance to revise the answer before a better answer from @rckd came in (around 3 months after this one).

Comment: Even though I am using angular js 1.4 I still find the $timeout solution useful with `ng-change` when I don't want to debounce the model.

Answer (score 9):

I know the question is too old. But still want to provide one quicker way to achieve this using [debouncing](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions).

So the code can be written as

```
<input ng-model="xyz" ng-change="FilterByName()" ng-model-options="{debounce: 500}"/>
```

Debounce will take the number in milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

or you can use directive ' typeahead-wait-ms="1000" ' from [angular-ui](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

```
<input 
   typeahead="name for name in filterWasChanged()"
   typeahead-wait-ms="1000"
   type="text" placeholder="search"
   class="form-control" style="text-align: right" 
   ng-model="templates.model.filters.name">
```