# Wait until user completes typing using ngChange - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

My `<input>` tag is associated with an Ajax call via ngChange.
What can I do to make sure that every change does not make an Ajax Request? Like ngChange function only executes once the user completes typing and waits for sometime, say 700ms.

I already tried `ng-model-options="{debounce: 700}"` but even then ngChange is executing for every keystroke.

Comment: try solutions from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446681/angular-ng-change-delay)

Comment: @entre Thanks. Solved. I was using AngularJS old version.

Answer (score 0):

depending on what you're definition is for completes typing, you could use [ng-blur](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur). ng-blur fires when a user leaves the input field

Comment: No.. I do not want the user to leave the input field. I am displaying search suggestions based on what the user typed.

Comment: @FaizuddinMohammed ok so you're not doing search suggestions?

Comment: Yes, I am. That is why I used ngChange on the input field. It's just that the ngChange function is executed too often. Any help on that?

Comment: @FaizuddinMohammed is it getting called more than just on a character change?

Comment: No, for every character change. And, that's exactly what I want to avoid.