# How do I stop all ongoing Ajax calls in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I'm making **Ajax** calls to an **API** triggered by an `ng-change` event in a text input element.

The HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="movieTitle" ng-change="writeTitle(movieTitle)">
```

The Javascript:

```
$scope.writeTitle = function(val){
  val = val.replace(/ /g, "+");
  var ajax_url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?s='+val+'*';
  $http.get(ajax_url).success(function(data) {
        $scope.movies = data.Search;
  });
}
```

What I want to do is, if someone types 4 characters in quick succession, only resolve the last **Ajax** call; otherwise they get mixed up sometimes and the user sees the result of a call other than the last one.

So, how do I stop ongoing Ajax calls whenever a new call is made and others are still on the queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you do this, is to limit how often you call a function, not by stopping further ajax calls per se.

The 2 common terms are either `throttling` or `debouncing` and with a H/T to [this blog](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing/)

**Throttling** - enforces a maximum number of times a function can be called over time. As in "execute this function at most once every 100 milliseconds.

**Debouncing** - enforces that a function not be called again until a certain amount of time has passed without it being called. As in "execute this function only if 100 milliseconds have passed without it being called.

You can choose whichever is more appropriate for your situation, and implement it in your function.

Comment: Thanks. All answers suggested similar things but yours is more complete so I'll accept this one. Just to be clear, though, I need to use either Lodash or Underscore.js, right?

Comment: @mustieles - or, simply look at the source code an extract the code for `debounce`/`throttle`. There's no point adding a whole library for 1 method, but if you already use either lodash/underscore, yes they're included. Another answer also gives you a pure angular solution (see [docs for `ngModelOptions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions)).

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. I've already applied the Lodash version and it works like a charm! I'll look into the pure angular solution.

Answer (score 2):

You need to delay the firing of your `ng-change`. For this you need to use `debounce`.

For its usage you can refer to the below link:

[Angular ng-change delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446681/angular-ng-change-delay)

Answer (score 1):

`Debounce` and `throttling` things are suitable for that. And if you want to cancel ongoing requiest for some reason you need to use [timeout parameter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) of `$http.get` call.