# ng-change event should be called only after typing is completed

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

I have a text field with ng-change event.Event should be called only when the user completed typing.How to delay calling the event?

```
<input type="text" ng-model="custname" ng-change="findCustName()">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular ng-change delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446681/angular-ng-change-delay)

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "completed". As can be seen in the answers below, you can either add a delay to ng-change, so it's triggered x ms after user stops typing. Or trigger the change on the *blur* event.

Comment: What is your definition of the user completed typing? Is it a time delay from when the user stops typing?

Comment: Clarify, When you think user has done typing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **`ng-blur`** instead

> A blur event fires when an element has lost focus.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="custname" ng-blur="findCustName()">
```

If you do not want to use ng-blur or lost focus, you can use the same ng-change with **`ng-model-options`**

As of Angular 1.3, you could use Angular ng-model-options directive

```
<input ng-change="findCustName()" ng-model-options="{debounce:1000}">
```

Comment: ng-blur will be called when focus is out

Comment: which is same as user completes typing

Comment: @Sajeetharan That is not true and requires assumptions to be made.  Grails needs to clarify what "completed typing" means

Comment: @BShaps@Sal What i mean from "Completed typing" is i dont want findCustName function gets triggered for each letter.For example if i type custname as John when i use ng-change event it gets called for each letter.So i want to call the function after a certain delay so that it gets called only once.Hope i made it clear.

Comment: @GrailsLearner ng-blur is the way then, try it and update

Comment: @Sajeetharan - Is there a way that i can call the function only once even though the text box doesnot lose the focus?

Comment: yes you can do that with debounce time  <input type="text" ng-model="custname"  ng-change="findCustName()"   ng-model-options="{debounce: 750}" />

Comment: Go with the debounce option, not the ng-blur for what you described.  `ng-blur` will work in most instances, but assumes the user will leave the input and won't be impacted by a few edge cases.  If you really want to make it trigger on blur or delay (what I would suggest), then you can use `ng-model-options="{debounce: 750, updateOn: 'blur'}"`

Comment: @BShaps `ng-model-options="{debounce: 750, updateOn: 'blur'}"` will cause the model value to update 750ms after focus is lost. If you want it to update on blur *or* delay you would use `ng-model-options="{debounce: {blur: 0, default: 750}, updateOn: 'blur default'}"`.

Comment: Yep, my syntax was bad.  Thanks for the correction Lex!

Answer (score 0):

When I want to call a function when typing is completed I use [`ng-keyup`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeyup).

Using `ng-keyup` your function will be call every time user press a key.

I know your asking when **user finish typing** , but let me explain why I prefer using `ng-keyup` and not `ng-blur`

If I have to call a validation function, `ng-blur` won't help, because you will have to focus out to launch the function. Using `ng-keydown`, function will be launch. so if user finished typing it will be launch also

Comment: It will not, because ng-keyup will fire the function but he don't know the length of the input. what will happen if i type only three words and then do nothing?
so the event of ng-change called after user has done typing, and what you are doing calling a function everytime user hit a key.

Answer (score 0):

i use this for call function after typing new value done.

```
ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" watch-selection
```