# Filter performance with ng-repeat with multiple ng-show inside

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a ng-repeat with multiple ng-show condition inside. Something like this (fictive example):

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:searchFilter" >
    <label ng-show="item.label==1">{{item.label}}</label>
    <label ng-show="item.label==2">{{item.label}}</label>
    <label ng-show="item.label==3">{{item.label}}</label>
    <label ng-show="item.label==4">{{item.label}}</label>
    <label ng-show="item.label==5">{{item.label}}</label>
    <label ng-show="item.label==1">{{item.label}}</label>
    <label ng-show="item.label==2">{{item.label}}</label>
    <label ng-show="item.label==1">{{item.label}}</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I am using ng-show for formatting purpose, e.g. :

I want to show the cellphone column, when the item.cellphone is not empty...

I have a big data source (+1000 rows) and I have noticed performance problem when I use the filter.

If I remove most of the ng-show conditions, the performance is good. Here's live example :

1. [Ng-show performance problem](http://jsbin.com/xatimihubu/1/)
2. [Without ng-show](http://jsbin.com/xatimihubu/2/)

I know you can improve the performance with a "track by" ([here's an topic about it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17971632/2171260)), but it look like it is not enough to make the filter "smooth" (at least, not too laggy).

Is there a way to improve the filter performance of ng-repeat with multiple ng-show condition and a large data source ?

Comment: You have way too many rows and watches. Some posts about Angular performance say you shouldn't have more than 2000 watches. In your example you have at least 4500 * 7! You need paging or the like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performance tuning really depends on some of the constraints that you're facing. Here are a few suggestions:

1) Do you really need to show/hide the labels, or will not creating them at all suffice? If they don't need to exist, use `ng-if` instead of `ng-show`. This will reduce the number of watchers as well as the number of DOM elements in your example drastically.

2) If you can use Angular 1.3+ and can assume the labels are static ids, use one-time binding to avoid having so many watchers `{{::label}}`

Modifying your example with these suggestions results in: http://jsbin.com/madefuqami/2/edit

Ultimately, however, if you keep adding elements then at some point your app will become slow. Angular's dirty-checker will look at each of these `ng-show` (or `ng-if`) and `{{}}` bindings on every `$digest` cycle. Plus the DOM will get unnecessarily large - there's a good chance that you don't need the browser to do all of the work associated with maintaining HTML and styling for element 3000 when only 1-50 fit on your screen.

A more robust solution would involve looking into pagination or virtualization. This can either be done server-side, or in Javascript.

I suggest server-side pagination. Ultimately, it will scale better and make for a cleaner solution. However, if you decide to go the Javascript virtualization route, there are libraries available already such as [angular-virtual-scroll](https://github.com/stackfull/angular-virtual-scroll)

Comment: 1) `ng-if` produces the same count of watches as `ng-show`

Comment: No it doesn't. Any watchers nested inside the `if` are saved. `<div ng-if="somethingFalsey"> {{someProperty}} </div>` does not have to watch `{{someProperty}}`. In this case this is up to 8 instances of `{{item.label}}`

Comment: You're right. With ng-if the watchers for {{...}} can be saved. But still the `ng-if` has to be watched and in his case there are 4500*7 (or 8 in SO example).

Comment: Hence my suggestion that he'll eventually have to go with pagination or virtualization (the whole bottom half of my answer). But until then, using `ng-if` is significantly better than `ng-show`, unless the element is required for some reason such as animation, and I believe that's something that's worth being aware of.

Comment: Absolutely right. Maybe a `ng-switch` could save more watches (in case ng-if conditions are mutually exclusive - the example seems to be a bit derived).