# Angular- two search inputs using same search function

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to implement two search inputs for one table with one search function in Angular

First input is searching in "Name" column, but second in "Description".
The issue is that when I write something in one of them then is automatically added in second one. I'm sending a parameter to the search function so I can select in which column it must look for a matches.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p5pu4p38/3/)
This is my HTML:

```
    <html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" ng-app lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/css/bootstrap.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/2.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var sortingOrder = 'name';
    </script>
</div>            
        <div ng-controller="ctrlRead">
            <div class="input-append">
                <span>Name</span>
                <input type="text" ng-model="query" ng-change="search('name')" class="input-large search-query" placeholder="Name">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-search"></i></span>
            </div>
            <div class="input-append">
                <span>Description</span>
                <input type="text" ng-model="query" ng-change="search('description')" class="input-large search-query" placeholder="Description">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-search"></i></span>
            </div>
            <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="id">Id&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('id')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a></th>
                        <th class="name">Name&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('name')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a></th>
                        <th class="description">Description&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('description')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a></th>
                        <th class="field3">Field 3&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('field3')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a></th>
                        <th class="field4">Field 4&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('field4')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a></th>
                        <th class="field5">Field 5&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('field5')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                    <td colspan="6">
                        <div class="pagination pull-right">
                            <ul>
                                <li ng-class="{disabled: currentPage == 0}">
                                    <a href ng-click="prevPage()">« Prev</a>
                                </li>
                                <li ng-repeat="n in range(pagedItems.length)"
                                    ng-class="{active: n == currentPage}"
                                ng-click="setPage()">
                                    <a href ng-bind="n + 1">1</a>
                                </li>
                                <li ng-class="{disabled: currentPage == pagedItems.length - 1}">
                                    <a href ng-click="nextPage()">Next »</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="item in pagedItems[currentPage] | orderBy:sortingOrder:reverse">
                        <td>{{item.id}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.description}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.field3}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.field4}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.field5}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my JS:

```
    function ctrlRead($scope, $filter) {
    // init
    $scope.sortingOrder = sortingOrder;
    $scope.reverse = false;
    $scope.filteredItems = [];
    $scope.groupedItems = [];
    $scope.itemsPerPage = 5;
    $scope.pagedItems = [];
    $scope.currentPage = 0;
    $scope.items = [
        {"id":"1","name":"John","description":"man","field3":"field3 1","field4":"field4 1","field5 ":"field5 1"}, 
        {"id":"2","name":"Artur","description":"man","field3":"field3 2","field4":"field4 2","field5 ":"field5 2"}, 
        {"id":"3","name":"David","description":"free","field3":"field3 3","field4":"field4 3","field5 ":"field5 3"}, 
        {"id":"4","name":"Simon","description":"free","field3":"field3 4","field4":"field4 4","field5 ":"field5 4"}, 
        {"id":"5","name":"John","description":"free","field3":"field3 5","field4":"field4 5","field5 ":"field5 5"}, 
        {"id":"6","name":"Artur","description":"free","field3":"field3 6","field4":"field4 6","field5 ":"field5 6"}, 
        {"id":"7","name":"David","description":"man","field3":"field3 7","field4":"field4 7","field5 ":"field5 7"}, 
        {"id":"8","name":"John","description":"man","field3":"field3 8","field4":"field4 8","field5 ":"field5 8"}, 
        {"id":"9","name":"Simon","description":"free","field3":"field3 9","field4":"field4 9","field5 ":"field5 9"}, 
        {"id":"10","name":"John","description":"man","field3":"field3 10","field4":"field4 10","field5 ":"field5 10"}, 
        {"id":"11","name":"Artur","description":"free","field3":"field3 11","field4":"field4 11","field5 ":"field5 11"}, 
        {"id":"12","name":"name 12","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 12","field4":"field4 12","field5 ":"field5 12"}, 
        {"id":"13","name":"name 13","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 13","field4":"field4 13","field5 ":"field5 13"}, 
        {"id":"14","name":"name 14","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 14","field4":"field4 14","field5 ":"field5 14"}, 
        {"id":"15","name":"name 15","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 15","field4":"field4 15","field5 ":"field5 15"}, 
        {"id":"16","name":"name 16","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 16","field4":"field4 16","field5 ":"field5 16"}, 
        {"id":"17","name":"name 17","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 17","field4":"field4 17","field5 ":"field5 17"}, 
        {"id":"18","name":"name 18","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 18","field4":"field4 18","field5 ":"field5 18"}, 
        {"id":"19","name":"name 19","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 19","field4":"field4 19","field5 ":"field5 19"}, 
        {"id":"20","name":"name 20","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 20","field4":"field4 20","field5 ":"field5 20"}
    ];

    var searchMatch = function (haystack, needle) {
        if (!needle) {
            return true;
        }
        return haystack.toLowerCase().indexOf(needle.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    };

    // init the filtered items
    $scope.search = function (param) {
        $scope.filteredItems = $filter('filter')($scope.items, function (item) {
            for(var attr in item) {
                if(param === undefined){
                    if (searchMatch(item[attr], $scope.query)){
                        return true;
                    }
                }else{
                    if (searchMatch(item[param], $scope.query)){
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        });
        // take care of the sorting order
        if ($scope.sortingOrder !== '') {
            $scope.filteredItems = $filter('orderBy')($scope.filteredItems, $scope.sortingOrder, $scope.reverse);
        }
        $scope.currentPage = 0;
        // now group by pages
        $scope.groupToPages();
    };

    // calculate page in place
    $scope.groupToPages = function () {
        $scope.pagedItems = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.filteredItems.length; i++) {
            if (i % $scope.itemsPerPage === 0) {
                $scope.pagedItems[Math.floor(i / $scope.itemsPerPage)] = [ $scope.filteredItems[i] ];
            } else {
                $scope.pagedItems[Math.floor(i / $scope.itemsPerPage)].push($scope.filteredItems[i]);
            }
        }
    };

    $scope.range = function (start, end) {
        var ret = [];
        if (!end) {
            end = start;
            start = 0;
        }
        for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
            ret.push(i);
        }
        return ret;
    };

    $scope.prevPage = function () {
        if ($scope.currentPage > 0) {
            $scope.currentPage--;
        }
    };

    $scope.nextPage = function () {
        if ($scope.currentPage < $scope.pagedItems.length - 1) {
            $scope.currentPage++;
        }
    };

    $scope.setPage = function () {
        $scope.currentPage = this.n;
    };

    // functions have been describe process the data for display
    $scope.search();

    // change sorting order
    $scope.sort_by = function(newSortingOrder) {
        if ($scope.sortingOrder == newSortingOrder)
            $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;

        $scope.sortingOrder = newSortingOrder;

        // icon setup
        $('th i').each(function(){
            // icon reset
            $(this).removeClass().addClass('icon-sort');
        });
        if ($scope.reverse)
            $('th.'+new_sorting_order+' i').removeClass().addClass('icon-chevron-up');
        else
            $('th.'+new_sorting_order+' i').removeClass().addClass('icon-chevron-down');
    };
};
ctrlRead.$inject = ['$scope', '$filter'];
```

Any Idea how can I fix this issue?

The source of search and table is from this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12670338/1732989)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because you have the same `ng-model` attribute for your two inputs.

```
$scope.query = {
  name: "",
  description: ""
}

$scope.search = function (model) {
  var word = $scope.query[model];
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right. I already realized this issue but now I'm trying somehow to change ng-model s without complication of search function.

Comment: I just edited my answer, providing what i would have done. Hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately don't. I don't have idea how to use it. I try something but all the time I get "undefined" for the model.

Comment: I made it but in different way. Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p5pu4p38/7/) Do you thing that like this is OK?
Unfortunately it doesn't work like I expect. For example when I wrote name- "Artur" I see 3 records. Next when I wrote description 'free' It's showing me all records with description 'free' but I want only this which have name="Artur"

Comment: You need to filter on both fields at the same time to make it work this way. You are currently filtering on the one passed as a parameter to `search`.

Comment: Yes I agree with you. It will be extremely hard to write everything in one function :/