# Starting position for ng-repeat angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to use `ng-repeat` but I need a specific starting position for pagination.

My code looks like this:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="hotel in hotels | filter:search  | orderBy:sortBy.Name :order.reverse | limitTo:itemsPerPage">
```

I am using `ng-repeat` with `limitTo(ex:5) directive`.
How can I set-up for `ng-repeat` an starting `index`?

Comment: Hint: Create a new [`$filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#creating-custom-filters) that will [`slice`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) the array in the given index.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pagination on a list using ng-repeat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581209/pagination-on-a-list-using-ng-repeat)

Comment: I have implemented the following filter in my app.js file: 

`app.filter('startFrom', function () {
        return function (input, start) {
            start = +start;
            return input.slice(start);
        }
    });`

I receive the data in an asynchronous way and the filter is applied at page load.
The problem is that the data is not available when the filter is used.

How can I have filter applied after the data is available?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to loop a subarray of the collection:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var subArray = arr.slice(1, 4);
print(subArray); // 2,3,4
```

Array.slice ref: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp