# Need to do a pagination on this ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, json, modal-dialog, pagination

I need to paginate this repeating sequence, so that there are only 5 items on one page and it has to load  on the same page, as it  fetches data from the json file, and it then sends it to ng-repeat, as the number of data is around 50-60 so i need that on different pages, the data that would be shown would be consisting of Image, name, type, description about the book

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="book in books">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img ng-src="{{book.ImageUrl}}" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <h3>{{book.Name}}</h3>
                <h5>{{book.Type}}</h5>
                <p>{{book.Description}}</p>
                <button class="btn btn-default">Read More</button> &nbsp; Social Icons will go here
                <br />
                <br />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581209/pagination-on-a-list-using-ng-repeat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pagination on a list using ng-repeat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581209/pagination-on-a-list-using-ng-repeat)

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/2ZzZB/56/

Answer (score 0):

I use **dirPagination.js** of this example:

https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination

[How to do paging in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816073/how-to-do-paging-in-angularjs)

Answer (score -1):

try dirPaginate for pagination

https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination

Comment: this is more like comment